setup cloud custodian auto-tagging resources
the instructions are very light on what you need to do to setup auto tag.   Does anyone have more details on what is needed?
- name: ec2-auto-tag-user
  resource: ec2
  mode:
    type: cloudtrail
    role: arn:aws:iam::{account_id}:role/CloudCustodianRole
    # note {account_id} is optional. If you put that there instead of
    # your actual account number, when the policy is provisioned it
    # will automatically inherit the account_id properly
    events:
      - RunInstances
  filters:
    - tag:CreatorName: absent
  actions:
    - type: auto-tag-user
      tag: CreatorName
      principal_id_tag: CreatorId

